# use of prototype in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am learning prototype in JavaScript and this is the code I am trying -

```
<script>
function employee(name, age, sex) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.sex = sex;
}

var trialcoder = new employee('trialcoder', 26, 'M');
//employee.prototype.salary = null;
trialcoder.salary = 19000;

document.write("salary is "+ trialcoder.salary);
</script>
```

**My thoughts**- To add another property we need to use `prototype` like - `employee.prototype.salary = null;` so on un commenting this line, I was expecting an error but it was not..let me know where I am wrong in the `prototype` concept.

Code Source - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_math.asp

Comment: Read  http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/

Comment: might be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work

Comment: please refer Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) henceforth, w3schools is a bit *iffy* with their concepts and explanations

Comment: @badZoke http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: not an answer to your question, but don't use `w3schools` as reference or for learning, they used to have (and i'm sure it is sill so, because of the this sample) many false informations and misleading informations/examples.

Comment: @Trialcoder Why were you expecting an error?

Comment: @badZoke I was expecting error on commenting the line `employee.prototype.salary = null;` as salary property is not mentioned in the employee function

Comment: @Trialcoder you can always set a property of an object otherwise your `this.name = name` would also not work. Using `employee.prototype.salary = null` set's the default value of `salary` for all `employee` objects to `null`  which otherwise is `undefined`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct, because when you called

```
var trialcoder = new employee('trialcoder', 26, 'M');
```

You got an object instance of `employee` and just like any other object you can add properties to your `trialcoder` object like

```
trialcoder.salary = 19000;
```

In this case, the salary property is only available to your `trialcoder` object and if you make another instance of `employee` like `var another = new employee()` you have no salary property in `another` object, but, if you do something like

```
function employee(name, age, sex) { //... }
employee.prototype.salary = 19000;
```

and then make instances like

```
var anEmp = new employee();
console.log(anEmp.salary); // 19000
```

Make another instance

```
var newEmp = new employee();
console.log(newEmp.salary); // 19000
```

if you want, you can

```
newEmp.salary = 10000;
console.log(anEmp.salary); // 10000
```

Which means, when you add a property in the `prototype` of a constructor (employee) then every object instance can share the same property and after making an instance from the constructor, you can change the property of an instance but this won't effect other instances. Hope it's clear enough now.

Comment: Ahh very well...crystal clear now with the concept +1 and a green tick

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right and you will not receive error because using prototype your setting property salary of class employee and after creating an object of your class ur are setting the property for that specific object,if you create another object you can set its property salary too
If you set property using prototype then all objects of that class will share that (salary) property .

Comment: @AlvinWong I think its little bit harsh to down vote a fresher just for small mistakes :)